# Control Panel (CP) Link Button is not working

Tags: control-panel, config, config-overrides

There's a button in the top right corner of every EE install that links to the front-end of the site. On one of my installs it's returning:

```
http:///
```

instead of the site's address.

Where can I change the setting for this button?

If you look at the html it's the anchor inside the "msm_sites" list item.

Comment: Are you using a htaccess to remove the index.php? In that case, you should add RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !URL  in order to skip the URL query string

Comment: I'm removing index.php but I do that on all my EE sites and they don't have this problem - so I don't think this is the issue. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That link comes from **Admin → General Configuration** - the setting named **URL to the root directory of your site**. I'm willing to bet you have "/" as the value there.

Comment: Thanks Derek - **URL to the root directory of your site** setting is what it should be: http://www.clientsite.com/ - any other ideas?

Comment: Check for `$config['base_url']` and `$config['site_index']` in your `config.php` file. Those values might be overriding the control panel if present.

Comment: You are a champion Derek! `$config['base_url']` was blank. Thank you!