# Control panel (CP) top right link not redirecting

Tags: control-panel

After upgrading to 2.5.5, the top right link that links & redirects to the client site is not working.

The link is there, and generates the correct URL, but redirect never happens and we're stuck with the blank page:

http://www.clientsite.com/?URL=http://www.clientsite.com/

What could be causing this issue?

Thanks everyone!

P.S. Unfortunately none of the solutions at the related [Control Panel (CP) Link Button is not working](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/control-panel-cp-link-button-is-not-working) issue worked.

Answer (score 1):

Okay - it turned out to be the .htaccess after all. Replaced previous rewrite that another developer had with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And the CP link now links correctly out to the main site.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue on a windows server only. Might that be related? Not an answer but it might narrow the issue down if so.

Comment: Thanks noregt. It's the same server (Unix) so that wasn't the case. Appreciate the feedback though!

Comment: Well I'll take a look at the .htaccess file too then!